# How to dynamically create a task in gradle plugin?

Tags: dynamic, gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm developing a gradle plugin and I'm facing with a problem while I try to dynamically create tasks.

Here is my code snippet:

```
apply plugin: BootstrapPlugin

bootstrapConfig {
    basedir = "C:/temp/unzip"
    componentList = [
        [
            zipName: "test1",
            zipVersion: "_2",
            zipNetworkLocation: "temp",
            zipUnpackLocation: "${basedir}"
        ],
        [
            zipName: "test2",
            zipVersion: "_1",
            zipNetworkLocation: "temp",
            zipUnpackLocation: "${basedir}"
        ]
    ]
}

class BootstrapPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    void apply(Project project){
        project.extensions.create("bootstrapConfig",BootstrapConfigPluginExtension)
        project.task("unzipAll", dependsOn: project.tasks.matching { Task task -> task.name.startsWith("unzipSingle")}){
           println "DOIT!"
        }

        project.bootstrapConfig.componentList.each { element ->
            project.task "unzipSingle${element.zipName}" (type: Copy)   {
                def artifactFile = new File(project.bootstrapConfig.shareUrl + "/" + element.zipNetworkLocation + "/" + element.zipName + element.zipVersion + ".zip")
                def pathDestination = element.zipUnpackLocation + "/" + element.zipName + element.zipVersion
                def touchFileName = pathDestination + "/" + element.zipName + element.zipVersion + ".pid"
                from project.zipTree(artifactFile)
                into pathDestination
            }
        }
    }
}

class BootstrapConfigPluginExtension {
    String basedir
    def componentList = []
}
```

When I try to run it the problem is that no one of the tasks I'm trying to create exists. Running `unzipAll` it only run that task as it depends from no others.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's how it goes:

1. All script statements are parsed in order they're declared.
2. `apply plugin: BootstrapPlugin` is executed.
3. At the time `BootstrapPlugin` is applied `bootstrapConfig` closure wasn't parsed yet. Since it wasn't parsed `BootstrapPlugin` knows nothing about the config and iterates over empty collection.
4. `bootstrapConfig` closure is parsed now when it's useless.

The solution is to create dynamic tasks in `afterEvaluate` block:

```
apply plugin: BootstrapPlugin

bootstrapConfig {
    basedir = 'C:/temp/unzip'
    shareUrl = 'http://lol.com'
    componentList = [
        [
            zipName: "test1",
            zipVersion: "_2",
            zipNetworkLocation: "temp",
            zipUnpackLocation: "${basedir}",
        ],
        [
            zipName: "test2",
            zipVersion: "_1",
            zipNetworkLocation: "temp",
            zipUnpackLocation: "${basedir}",
        ],
    ]
}

class BootstrapPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
  void apply(Project project){
    project.extensions.create('bootstrapConfig', BootstrapConfigPluginExtension)
    project.afterEvaluate {
      project.task("unzipAll", dependsOn: project.tasks.matching { Task task -> task.name.startsWith("unzipSingle")}){
        println "DOIT!"
      }

      project.bootstrapConfig.componentList.each { element ->
        project.task("unzipSingle${element.zipName}",type: Copy) {
          def artifactFile = new File(project.bootstrapConfig.shareUrl + "/" + element.zipNetworkLocation + "/" + element.zipName + element.zipVersion + ".zip")
          def pathDestination = element.zipUnpackLocation + "/" + element.zipName + element.zipVersion
          def touchFileName = pathDestination + "/" + element.zipName + element.zipVersion + ".pid"
          from project.zipTree(artifactFile)
          into pathDestination
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

class BootstrapConfigPluginExtension {
    String basedir
    String shareUrl
    def componentList = []
}
```

Now the tasks do exist and can be run, however they won't be listed with `gradle tasks`.

[Here](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/34152407) is the demo.

Comment: Wonderful, it explains clearly the problem and works fine. Thanks a lot!